# Editext Not taking Numerical input due to setOnKeyListener

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText`, its taking inputs of letters and different symbols however not numbers. Additionally, I have set the `EditText` on `setOnKeyListener` to close the virtual keyboard by pressing Enter. Observed and found out that it failing to take numerical inputs due to the below code

Code for setting virtual keyboard to hide after pressing enter

```
durOnTreadmill.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) 
        { 
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(durOnTreadmill.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
        return true;
    }

});
```

my EditText in XML

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/durOnTreadmill"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="hh:mm:ss" />
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should only return `true` from `onKey` if you're handling the input. I.e., move the `return true` inside your `if` block and `return false` otherwise.

Comment: worked like a grenade ;) thanks dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying my comment here:

> You should only return true from onKey if you're handling the input.
>   I.e., move the return true inside your if block and return false
>   otherwise.

Comment: I seem that if I write `editText.setOnKeyListener { true }` then `editText` will not receive hardware keyboard events, and this true. But why numeric from virtual keyboard are ignored too in this case?

Answer (score 1):

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

in you EditText xml will dissmiss the keyboard when the user hits enter
and you say that it wont except numbers you have the input set to "text"

take this line out:

```
android:inputType="text"
```

Comment: Sorry about extremely late reply, I already tried the inputType method. Keypad is hiding as intended but EditText still doesn't allow numerical input :). Tushar's comment worked for me. Thanks for your advice though. :)

Comment: no problem, glad you got it working, i never even used onKeyListener for edittext im still learning myself

Comment: learning has no age dude, glad my post has been helpful for you :)